# Get values of range object without using 'for' loop

Tags: python

It seems `range()` doesn't have a method of getting values (something like `dict().values()`).

Is there a way of getting the values without doing "manual" iteration (like `[x for x in range(10)]`)?

Comment: @slothrop Could you please turn this into an answer with explanation how `[*range(10)]` works? This is novel to me. I'd accept such answer. P.S. if there's solution for this in C (how to get an array of values without manual iteration) that would be nice as well

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the values? Most things you could do with the list you could do with the range anyway (it's an [immutable sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually I'd just like to see the values in a Jupyter notebook..

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U See [6.15. Expression lists](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists): "An asterisk * denotes iterable unpacking."...'

Comment: I'd say the equivalent to `dict().values()` ***is*** the `range()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of the values: `list(range(10))` or `[*range(10)]`

To get a tuple: `tuple(range(10))`

That concise `[*range(10)]` solution makes use of the syntax introduced in [PEP 448 ("Additional unpacking generalisations")](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/). Generically, if `itb` is some finite iterable, then `[*itb]` is the list formed by iterating over its elements.

For example, using a generator as the iterable:

```
def squares_gen(n):
  for i in range(n):
    yield i**2

res = [*squares_gen(5)]
print(type(res))
print(res)
```

prints:

```
<class 'list'>
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting range object to list will do the job.

```
print(list(range(10)))
```

output:

```
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Alternatively,

```
print(set(range(10)))
```

returns

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert the range values into a list you can do the following:

```
numbers = list(range(10)) #Get a list with values from 0 to 9
print(numbers) #Print the list
print(type(numbers)) #To see that numbers is really a list
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
<class 'list'>
```